# Find distinct accounts and fetch their respective record ids?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to fetch person account records that are unique and I'm trying an aggregate query as such:

```
SELECT count(Id), FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail FROM Account 
WHERE IsPersonAccount = true 
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail HAVING count(Id)=1
```

This works fine and all, but now I somehow need to fetch the actual recordID from the result above to do some further manipulation - how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You should be able to modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail FROM Account 
WHERE IsPersonAccount = true 
Order BY Id, LastName, FirstName, PersonEmail
```

This should give you the results you're looking for. BTW, any query will return the Record Id by default. You shouldn't have accounts with the same AccountId in your system. Duplicate accounts will also be returned, but they'd also be readily visible in your results using the above method as the Last name and email would likely be identical unless the person used a different email address.

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting an error saying
`Grouped field should not be aggregated: Id`



```BTW, any query will return the Record Id by default```,
 I'm not getting the id in the aggregate result actually.. just firstname, lastname, personemail

Comment: Then you'll need to run this without the count(Id). That's why you're getting the error message. That way you can group by `Id`. Your query will no long be an aggregate query unless you do something like `count(PersonEmail)` and use `Count(PersonEmail)=1` since the `PersonEmail` address should also be unique. That's how I'd recommend you approach this if you don't dedupe. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: But that defeats the whole purpose of even doing the query in the first place? That just returns all records with their respective ids.

Comment: Yes, I realized that as I began to edit the post. It won't allow you to display PersonEmail. If you have a different field to get count from on a field that should be unique to Account, that would be the way to do it. then again, all your Ids will be unique, so you could Order By Id

Comment: Well, to give the story some background - here's what I'm trying to achieve (maybe there is a simpler process). 

All incoming cases should be assigned to an existing account IF the case email matches an email on the person account AND that person account the sole account with that email.

I.e if two person accounts exists with `customer@email.com` and a case is created with that email - don't link the case to anything. If only one person account exists with `customer@email.com` and a case is created with that email: link the account to that case.

Comment: Are you implementing a custom email parser?  The default Email to Case settings should automatically handle this matching by email (as far as I remember).  If this is at the trigger level, just do the SOQL query `WHERE PersonEmail = :incomingEmailAddress` and check if the size is 1

Comment: What we did is create an Account Search that returns all potential related accounts for a contact with that email address. If there's more than one, the Agent would need training to know to use the WebAccount Field on the Case Object. This is for a Lightning Console situation. You should be able to use the related list component for this purpose without needing any code.

Comment: @BrianMiller yeah - the reason I'm turning to a custom solution is that we want to have the same logic for all case integration endpoints - if case comes from third party serives / web-to-case / email-to-case. Also, I wish to extend the functionality beyond just email, for instance by looking at a combo of first and last name as well.
`WHERE PersonEmail = :incomingEmailAddress` feels terribly inefficient if I were to bulk-insert cases?

Comment: @erikvm It depends on how many EmailMessages you're pushing at any given time, and I don't think `WHERE PersonEmail in :incomingEmailAddresses` would be such a slow query as opposed to anything else you need to accomplish your goal.  If you're really manually uploading tons of email messages in one shot, you could move this whole operation over to a Apex Batch/Scheduled job that does all the associations post-facto, in which case performance is less of an issue

Comment: If I provide a list of emails and use the `WHERE PersonEmail in :incomingEmailAddresses` statement - does it check each individual email? What if that list has three email addresses, two of which already exist